# How to escape Intro in a python shell

Tags: python

I normally use the python shell to test small things, with no needed to make a new .py file.

I wanted to test something like:

```
>>> def a : 
     pass
```

but i don't know how to scape the intro. I tried on the same line

```
>>> def a: pass
```

but throws a syntax error, for the indentation I suppose

Comment: If it's a one-line test, why not use `lambda: None`?

Comment: Because presumably that's only an example.

Comment: It _is_ a syntax error try: `def a(): pass`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for a single-line [function definition](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) is:

```
def a(): pass
```

You were missing the non-optional `()` (e.g `def a(arg1, arg2): pass`)

Comment: I believe the term for "non-optional" is "required" :^)  (+1)

Comment: You are right.
My first question on stackoverflow and was a stupid one,sry and thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question was about trimming initial indentation, and not about the specific line you posted, you can't with the vanilla interpreter. You'd need something more robust. If I remember correctly, `ipython` does something like that. Or you can add it to your favorite interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting parens after your function name:

```
>>> def f():
...     print "test"
...
>>> f
<function f at 0xfff37764>
>>> f()
test
```